# Multiple Apps with CouchDB

Tags: security, process, couchdb

What is the recomended security model for running multiple apps with CouchDB? The apps are separate from each other apps and DBs are in a 1:1 relationship, and it makes sense for them not to be able to access each others' data.

Should the databases run in their own CouchDB instance or is there a way to combine them? I've seen a little about authentication and authorization, but there's not enough to tell if it's viable to support different users on the same instance. And on the other hand, if there's much overhead to running separate instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a _security document for each database, preventing access by username or role.

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authorization

The primary consideration when running multiple applications on one CouchDB server is that all user accounts will be shared. There is one central `_users` database for everybody.

Comment: +1 I took the liberty of mentioning that all user accounts are shared on a couch.